# Finding time and space complexity of this program

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

```py
    def g3(n):
        s = 0
        i = 1
        while i < n:
            i *= 2
            s += i
        return s
    
    def f3(n):
        s = []
        i = 2
        while (i < n):
            s.append(g3(i))
            i *= i
        return s
```

I am trying to calculate the time and space complexity of the function `f3`, I am reaching some wrong answer, and I can't get where is my mistake, the final answer is time complexity: `O(log(n))`, space complexity `O(log(log(n)))`. 
My work:

First I decided to calculate time complexity of function `g3` since `f3` calls it inside the loop. the values of `i` are `2^k` after `k` iterations and it stops whenever `2^k >= n` which means `k=log(n)`. so now I know that time complexity of `g3` is `log(n)`. 
Moving on to `f3` inside the loop, the values of `i` are `2,4,16,256` or in another words `2^(2^k)` and it stops whenever `2^(2^k) >= n` so we get `k = log(log(n))`. 
Now in order to calculate the whole time complexity of `f3`, I know that the function `f3` calls `g3` `log(log(n))` times in total. So the time complexity should be something like this:

```
[log(2^(2^0))+log(2^(2^1))+...+log(2^(2^(log(log(n)))]*log(n)
```

Note that all of them are multiplied by `log(n)` since each call iterates `log(n)` times in `g3` (or atleast I understood it like that). 
Now I got stuck here as I feel I went so far and made some mistakes, and I can't figure out the total time complexity and can't see it being `O(log(n))`, I would really appreciate any help or feedback. 
Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right reasoning until the very moment when you computed the complexity. Each call does not iterate `log(n)` times in `g3` but `log(2^(2^k))` at the `k`-th iteration.

Let us take one iteration `k` of `f3`. This iteration has complexity `log(2^(2^k)))`. Since `k` goes from `1` to `N=floor(log(log(n)))`, the total complexity is the sum from `k=1` to `N` of the `log(2^(2^k))`. Using the property `log(a^b) = b*log(a)`, this gives us a time complexity equal to the sum of `2^k` from `1` to `N` (getting rid of multiplicative constants), which gives us, once again getting rid of multiplicative constants, a time complexity in `O(2^N)`. Since `N=log(log(n))`, we finally get a time complexity of `2^(log(log(n)))`. Since `log` refers to the base-2 logarithm here, this finally fives us a complexity of `O(log(n))`.

Concerning the time complexity, you store `O(log(log(n)))` times a value, which gives a space complexity of `O(log(log(n)))`.